# Google Geocoder Find if Address was Geocoded to Postcode level or Address level

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have DB with over than 3k UK addresses. I'm able to geocode them and put markers on the map. I'm just wondering if it's possible to find them which where Geocoded to postcode level and don't display them on map ignore them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure google's geocoding service returns an accuracy value, you could ignore those where it's too low

Comment: The response of Geocoding service contains a `types` fields, so if you see something like `"types":[
        "postal_code"
      ]`, this is a postal code and not an address.